# How do I say "I understand much better than before."?

Tags: words, greetings, phrases

Or "I understand much better now." If someone helped me with a translation and I responded with: どうもありがとうございます。前より上手に分かっています。 Would that be the correct way to express that in Japanese?

Comment: http://esaura.cc/
 is great for translation questions. A typical phrase in japanese for this situation is 勉強になりました though it is obviously not a direct translation

Comment: Even in English, though, this is sort of a weird thing to say. (At least it's a very formal way of saying it.)

I think it'd be better just as "I get it" or a simple "わかりました".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A typical phrase in japanese for this situation is "勉強になりました", though it is obviously not a direct translation. Maybe you could say:

> 前よりもっと分かりました

Or from Chocolateさん:

> 前よりずっと理解が深まりました

Comment: If my answer is passable, can anyone tell me if this way would be unnatural? 前よりもっと分かりになりました

Comment: also would 前よりはもっと分かりました be better?

Comment: So two questions: How did 勉強になりました, `became to study`, come to mean what I wrote above? Also, why is it 分かりました instead of 分かります?

Comment: there are many meanings of naru besides become= http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1E. in this instance i think it would mean something more like  "I studied it to a point of understanding/fully grasping it".

Comment: @yadokari-san, We don't say「分かりになりました」... How about 「前よりずっと理解が深まりました」?

Comment: ＠chocolate thank you that sounds good. @dotnet maybe because in the past tense it emphasizes that the understanding process is finished. To my non-expert ears the past tense here sounds better, but i think the present tense could work as well.

Comment: @Chocolate could you use もっと instead of ずっと?

Comment: @dotnetN00bsan, Hmm 前よりもっと sounds to me like you're comparing "this time" with "前=last time"... I mean, if you say 前よりもっと分かった/前よりわかった (=前より+past tense), I think it implies that you understood better "this time", but you didn't understand that much "last time you were taught"... so maybe I'd say 前よりずいぶん(orずっと)理解が深まりました/お陰で、(orお陰様で、)ずいぶん理解が深まりました/前よりずいぶんわかって"きました"(not the simple present when you add 前より-- then this 前 sounds like "以前, before")/ずいぶんわかってきました/or just とてもよくわかりました/お陰様でとてもよくわかりました or お陰様で、かなり分かって"きました"。

Comment: @Chocolate That's really hard to read as a comment...

Comment: @dotnetN00bsan, Eww, Gomen~! どうしよう・・・^^;

Answer (score 2):

I doubt one says "上手に"+"分かる", since 分かる is "come to be understood", rather than "actively understand".

The suggested 勉強になりました is pretty common.

If you really want to say "I understand much better than before", you could say "やっと、分かってきた", "やっと理解するようになった", or "前より理解できた". Although *I* would probably add "かも(しれない)" at the end of all these examples, to be somewhat less assertive about my comprehension faculties.